# SQL Join with multiple columns and added rows

Tags: sql

I have a table table_base where the unique key comes in multiple columns. I have got 10 such columns where unique values can come. I am showing only three here.

table_base

```
col1  col2 col3  
A1      A2        
A4      A1    A2
```

I want to verify this data from another table in the system and get the total number 5 records.
As there are five numbers( A1,A2,A4,A1,A2).But I am getting unique records .

I have written this code but getting unique records.

```
with test as(
Select a.*,b.pri_check from table_base left join 
table_check b on 
b.pri_check in ( a.col1,  a.col2 a.col3 ))
select a.Col1 ,
case when col1 = pri_check then 'Yes' else 'No' endcase.
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1 check
A1   Yes  
A2   No  
A4   No  
A1   Yes  
A2   No
```

Regards,
AG

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What's the logic of `check` column?

Comment: when col1 = pri_check then 'Yes' else 'No' endcase